# SASS/SCSS is there a way to merge a two 1D lists into a single 2D list?

Tags: list, sass, each

In SCSS, I want to merge the following lists:

```
$animals: dog, cat, rabbit, horse;
$colors: brown, orange, white, black;
```

Into something like this:

```
$mylist: dog brown, cat orange, rabbit white, horse black;
```

Is this possible? I then want to use the 2d list like this:

```
@each $animal, $color in $mylist {
   .my_#{$animal} {
     color: $color;
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`zip()`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#zip-instance_method) function:

```
$animals: dog, cat, rabbit, horse;
$colors: brown, orange, white, black;

@each $animal, $color in zip($animals, $colors) {
   .my_#{$animal} {
     color: $color;
   }  
}
```

Note that this is a Sass 3.3 feature.